# Function does not remove and add class

Tags: javascript, html

I have a script that basically is to remove the class **"no-js"** from the body and add the class **"js"**, but the script is not working. What did I do wrong?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <title> Infusion </title>     
    </head>
    
    <body class="no-js">
    </body>
</html>



function removeClassBody(){
    var body = document.querySelector('body');
    body.classList.remove('no-js');
    body.classList.add('js');
}

()removeClassBody;
```

Comment: `()removeClassBody;` is a syntax error. You should be getting an error message on this in your browser console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call the function like thie removeClassBody();

```js
function removeClassBody(){
    var body = document.querySelector('body');
    body.classList.remove('no-js');
    body.classList.add('js');
}

removeClassBody();
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <title> Infusion </title>     
    </head>
    
    <body class="no-js">
    </body>
</html>
```